# Dig doman.com @nameserver shows two inconsistent A records for one domain

Tags: dns, ip-address, a-records

I've asked a tech in another company to point a domain they control (say, odddomain.com) at one of my IP addresses (108.59.2.66). Before this, it was pointed to their ip, nn.nn.nn.nn. He's emailed to say all is well and done.

I run

```
whois odddomain.com
```

and get told that ns27.domaincontrol.com is one of the two authoritative DNS for this domain.

So I run

```
dig odddomain.com @NS28.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
```

and get

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
odddomain.com.  3600    IN  A   nn.nn.nn.nn
odddomain.com.  3600    IN  A   108.59.2.66

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
odddomain.com.  3600    IN  NS  ns28.domaincontrol.com.
odddomain.com.  3600    IN  NS  ns27.domaincontrol.com.
```

Same results for "dig odddomain.com @NS28.DOMAINCONTROL.COM"

Are the two inconsistent answers for odddomain.com's ip coming from different dns controllers? I'm not sure how I'd create a situation like this, so I don't know how to tell my colleague to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague got back to me. He really did have the two, inconsistent A records in his DNS tables. He removed one of them, and now dig reports all is well.